# My favicon code isn't working.... I did the code like it said in a guide

Tags: javascript, html, github, github-pages, favicon

So I'm building a website for my friend using Github hosting, and I want it to have a favicon. I have implemented this code:

```
<!--Favicon-->
    <!-- Opera Speed Dial Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />

<!-- Standard Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />

<!-- For iPhone 4 Retina display: -->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="favicon.png">

<!-- For iPad: -->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="favicon.png">

<!-- For iPhone: -->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="favicon.png">
```

but whenever I open the page, there's no favicon. I got the code from this guide [here](http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/examples/favicons/), but alas, it's not working... If someone could help me it'd be greatly appreciated... The github pages version can be found [here](https://nicholasrousom.github.io/aboutme/).

Comment: can you navigate to the favicon files directly in your browser?  Try that to make sure the paths are correct.  I've also seen this in the past where I change a favicon, and the browser just doesn't see that a change was made (cache) until I go visit it directly.

Comment: I changed it to `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://thisisaxels.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/favicon.png" />` so the icon is hosted with my personal blog, which worked for my other website, but it dosen't work either...

Comment: Also the icon is in the root directory. Same as the .html file

Comment: Are you sure that URL is correct?  I visited http://thisisaxels.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/20‌​17/11/favicon.png and I get the 404 error page

Comment: Yeah. This is it here: http://thisisaxels.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/favicon.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've put the `<link>` tag for the favicon inside the `<body>` tag, but it needs to be in the `<head>`

[image]

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much. Seems it was a realllly dumb mistake for me to make :facepalm: but now it's fixed so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I accessed the website from Firefox and the favicon appeared correctly. When I accessed in Chrome, an error occurred while trying to open the file '/favicon.ico'. 
This is because some browsers ignore the url inside the href tag and search only for a file named '/favicon.ico' in root directory. 
So, to solve your problem just create a file called "favicon.ico" in the root directory, replace the url in link tag and all browsers will recognize the favicon. Like this:

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

Comment: I did this, however it didn't work for me. I did exactly what you said. The source code is available [here](https://nicholasrousom.github.io/aboutme/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it after ;

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><link class="favi0" rel="icon" href="blah.png" />
```

You just need to put the code after (head)